Why are java varargs arrays
Recently I had a situation where it was logical to use varargs in java. I then found out that varargs are just syntactic sugar for arrays, and was curious about the performance repercussions that suggests. I read about it a little and found a couple of posts, and as one would safely assume, it's slower than using normal arguments. I also came across methods like EnumSet.of(...) which have along the lines of 5 different overloads to avoid having to use varargs because of performance reasons. I am not here to talk about that though. What I am curious about is why they were implemented as arrays in the first place.
In C++ for example, you have parameter packs, which aren't arrays. Is there some sort of historical reason for this?
There seems to be a bit of a discussion about performance going on. Again and I'd like to clarify: I haven't benchmarked anything. I mentioned the performance problems because they seem to exist as even in the JDK, there is code that goes around using varargs in certain cases for performance. And also, performance isn't the only limitation that roots from having varargs be implemented as an array. Another thing you cannot do with java varargs for example is forward the arguments to another function, or in other words - unpack them.

It is tradeoff. In java you have performance problem, in C++ you have read out-of-bounds attack. Also they was added late and no one wanted to change invocation standard.

"why they were implemented as arrays in the first place." - you must ask the developers, or someone involved in its development - most of us can only tell you our opinion (guess) But which other (simple) alternatives can you think of, without having to change the whole language? -- BTW you should have completed the [tour]: "Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based"

If you're concerned about that minor performance impact you're probably in for some premature optimization. In most cases changing architecture or algorithms will have a larger effect on performance that questions like whether to use single parameters or arrays. And if you're really in a situation where language feature performance is a legit concern the question of whether the language itself is suitable for your problem might arise. Java is a great language but for sure has different tradeoffs between performance and safety than other languages.

Did you benchmark this?  Are you sure there's a measurable performance decrease?  I would doubt this somewhat.  I'd imagine that any slowdown caused by using varargs would be measured in nanoseconds.  I also don't know what alternative you'd propose.

@user85421 There is a good chance the decision was documented on email lists or other publicly available sources, or that a member of the design team can answer this question. Both of those have happened in SO. So, while I agree that it's far from guaranteed that we'll get an objective answer here, there is an objective answer, and it's well within the sphere of possibility that we can get it here. Imo the question is on-topic in that regard.

Relevant

Regarding parameter packs: I don't know how those are implemented, but iirc, a lot of C++ comes down to "the compiler expands your code into N similar copies, one for each different usage". A parameterized class is actually several classes, one per instantiation. Java doesn't do this as a general principle, so the decision not to do it for varargs is consistent with the language's overall approach.

Your recent edit (" I suppose for the sake of clarity can we first establish what the benefits of having varargs be implemented as arrays provide if any?") makes the question broader. Now you're not just asking why the decision was made, but also getting down the path of interactively/conversationally reviewing that decision. At this point it does start getting off topic. I would suggest getting back to asking for the actual reasons — and being content with the fact that you may not get an answer, if the right people don't happen across this question.

@yshavit a while back I read about what you are referring to and the reason for java not doing the "parameterized class is actually several classes" thing is because of type erasure. Now there are reasons for type erasure, but I don't think that they apply to varargs. I suppose it's not impossible the reason is principle consistency though.

I think type erasure was as much a solution to the problem as it was a constraint. The real problem was backwards compatibility, and type erasure was a good-enough solution. Btw, you may also want to check out https://langdev.stackexchange.com. I'm not very familiar with that site's norms, but a similar question to this might be appropriate there.

@yshavit I just saw the relevant post about why asking a language specification question is opinionated so I tried to change it up a bit. To be honest I would also be satisfied with what are the benefits, but I I'll change it back to keep it on topic as at this point it might be a bit late.

@yshavit the problem was indeed backwards compatibility, but for varargs there shouldn't be a problem with backwards compatibility. I can't think of a scenario where the code would actively have to be changed because varargs got introduced. And I'll check it out.

"Another thing you cannot do with java varargs for example is forward the arguments to another function" - are you referring to "unpacking" varargs? If the other function accepts varargs or an array, you can forward it directly, foo(String... args) accepts an array. The only tricky thing would be trying to forward varargs to a function that does not take varargs/arrays. For example foo(String first, String second), requiring you to unpack your varargs and passing them directly foo(args[0], args[1]), in which case you could for example not automatically decide which overload to pick.

What about a method foo(String[]) that you want to convert to foo(String...)? Tbh my Java is quite rusty at this point, but I think the newly vararg'd version would be backwards compatible with code that used the explicit array version, both at source and bytecode. But — unfortunately I have to head out for the evening, sorry!

@Zabuzard I was referring to unpacking. And yeah I am talking about that tricky thing.

@talex It’s not a tradeoff, and you do not have out of bounds errors in C++ for parameter packs. On the contrary: the access is checked at compile time, whereas Java varargs out of bounds access creates runtime errors — C++ parameter packs are safer than Java varargs. (There are other, good reasons for why Java uses arrays, but it’s categorically not due to the reason you suggested).

@yshavit that does work but it's because they are quite literally the same thing. In fact you can't declare these two functions in the same scope, because the compiler will tell you that you have two "foo" functions defined. Good night!

well, maybe this question is not primarily opinion-based, I still believe it is, but it seems to fit the "Avoid questions ..., or that are likely to generate discussion" part from the [tour] (regarding the comments so far)

"What I am curious about is why they were implemented as arrays in the first place." - as opposed to what, exactly? And how might that theoretically work in Java? And what could it look like, syntactically, and in terms of the type system? Keep in mind you also have to think about unpacking. C++ "parameter packs" are untyped raw bytes on the stack.

@KonradRudolph "On the contrary: the access is checked at compile time" - across translation units? Really? How (i.e., where could the necessary information exist at compile time)?

@KarlKnechtel I think you’re confusing variadic arguments and parameter packs. The latter are template arguments, not untyped raw bytes.

@KonradRudolph I'm afraid I have no concept of how templates achieve varargs, then.

@KarlKnechtel There’s a (very basic) example on the cppreference page.

This post is being discussed on Meta.

It boils down to the following:

It keeps the language specification simple.
It keeps the language implementation simple.
It keeps user code (accessing varargs within a function) simple.
It does not cost much, because memory allocation (i.e. the allocation of an array to hold parameters) is extremely fast in Java.

But most importantly, as I will show:

The minuscule performance penalty of using an array for varargs is suffered only in varargs function invocations, while all other function invocations become slightly smaller and faster.


First of all, parameter packs did not exist in C++ back at the time that Java was laid down, so let us not compare apples with oranges: We have to compare java varargs with old C-style varargs.
Now, varargs are possible in C only under the default calling convention, which is cdecl. (If you try using some other calling convention, like stdcall, you cannot have varargs.)
Under the cdecl calling convention, any function can actually be invoked with any number of parameters, and this does not result in spectacular crashes all over the place, because it is the caller, who knows how many parameters they pushed into the stack, who is responsible for popping them from the stack once the function returns, to keep the stack balanced.
A cdecl function invocation under x86 looks like this:
push arg1              ;4 bytes
push arg2              ;4 bytes
call function
add sp, 8              ;balance the stack.

So, under the default calling convention in C, every single function invocation that is passed one or more parameters has to be followed with a stack-balancing instruction. This represents a performance penalty on all function invocations, regardless of whether they are varargs or not.
I have always thought that this is a bit retarded.
In Java, they decided that they are not going to have different calling conventions, and that the number of parameters to each function will be cast in stone. This way, they could make the function, rather than the caller, responsible for balancing the stack.
In x86, this is done like so:
ret 8                  ;return, also popping 8 bytes.

This is a much more sensible language design choice. Unfortunately, it appears to mean that the language cannot have varargs.
Well, sure it can, by implementing them using an array.
This wheel has already been invented, so why not reuse it?
Thus, varargs invocations in Java might cost slightly more than the absolute bare minimum imaginable, but every single non-varargs invocation is slightly more optimal, so this is a clear winner.

I suppose that does makes sense. A bit unrelated but C does have a calling convention that has the callee clean up the stack. And (I just found that out) that does mean you can't use  varargs so the compiler just changes the calling convention.

@iexav I amended my answer to account for the different calling conventions of C.

C does allow forwarding varargs; since C89 stdarg.h va_list supports this (compare printf and vprintf in stdio.h) and even before that implementations had methods, mostly a pointer to consecutive memory cells (which is C is an array), which is why the standard addressed it -- and why it requires standard-varargs be declared with a prototype containing ... while fixed-arg functions with K&R1-compatible types can be used without a prototype, and (until C99) if they return int without any declaration at all.

To answer the question, I'll present some analysis of choices, followed by my interpretation why the Java designers chose the array-based solution.
Analysis
"varargs" means that a call can provide a variable number of arguments that the method being called receives as one parameter entity, with properties like

have strongly typed elements,
can iterate over all individual arguments,
can retrieve the individual arguments by index,
or similar.

Whatever happens under the hood, the receiving parameter will look quite similar to an array or list. And of course, the compiler and the underlying JVM must have support for the mechanism chosen, either by reusing something that is already supported, or by extending it. So, what are the choices?

In the core Java language and the underlying virtual machine, the array data type is supported and fits these requirements. It's just the compiler that needs a special handling when a method with varargs exists that matches the call arguments list.
Using something from the Collections framework with its types like e.g. ArrayList  brings no relevant advantages (e.g. changing the length of the argument list is rarely useful), but forces boxing of primitive types like int into Integer.
Having the caller place the individual arguments onto the JVM stack, just like all "normal" arguments, without packing them into a heap-allocated array or list, needs some heavy extensions or modifications to the JVM. The method being called no longer knows how deep the stack is, making argument referenceing and unwinding the stack at method return more complex. And still the caller needs to receive an object that combines the arguments and supports access to its elements. This needs a JVM-supported special class just for that case.

Interpretation
Given that varargs are not used very often, the Java designers chose a mechanism that could re-use the existing JVM without special modifications. This is in line with many other Java extensions, that tried to keep the JVM as stable as possible.
Of the two remaining choices (array vs. List), the decision for array has less overhead and is superior in its element-type handling. E.g. there is a native int[], but no ArrayList<int>, only ArrayList<Integer>.
The varargs feature was introduced with Java 5, and I guess the Java team was already very busy with the other Java 5 features like generics, so investing into a major JVM modification just to support varargs was probably considered "not worth the effort".
And there still is the Hotspot compiler that translates JVM bytecode into machine language. In that process, it applies lots of clever transformations. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a special detection of varags patterns that can be replaced by classic calls.
